# Html <ul><li><ul> in a table pushes down the second row

Tags: html, list

I have a table of two rows filled with unordered list/ordered list elements that expand when the user moves a mouse over them. However, they also push down the rest of the table when expanded. How should I fix this? Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/aSevovIs/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the < ul > elements position property absolute, it will give an impression of floating div and it won't mess up the table height.

Answer (score 2):

To your `ul li ul` rule add `position:absolute;` and add a new rule:

```
td {
    position:relative;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ha9BP/)**

Comment: +1 for "Always post your code..." with your answer. *You will probably want to add a `z-index` and `background`... http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/Ha9BP/1/

Comment: Thanks, I needed the position:absolute; property only